# Calling saveRecord: after changing value of one field not updating existing iCloud record

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cloudkit

I am using the following code to retrieve a records, change a field in the retrieved record and store it back using saveRecord:.  I am noticing that saveRecord dos not return an error but the record is not updated in the dashboard.

I see a caveat in saveRecord: reference that it will only work if record being saved is newer than existing record.  How do I make it newer?  Wont updating a field not do it?

The NSLogs prints that I get while executing the code are after the code.

**EDIT** Using CKModifyRecordsOperation to save instead of saveRecord works.  Code is below.  So, I guess with saveRecord, we need to do something more (change tag?) to make it work?

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title = %@", @"MacKerricher State Park"];
CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:@"Artwork" predicate:predicate];
[publicDatabase performQuery:query inZoneWithID:nil completionHandler:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        // Error handling for failed fetch from public database
         NSLog(@"Failed to retrieve record due to error %@",error) ;
    }
    else {
        // Modify the record and save it to the database
        if([results count])
        {
            CKRecord *artworkRecord = (CKRecord *)results[0] ;
            NSLog(@"Retrieved record %@",artworkRecord) ;
            //NSDate *date = ;
            artworkRecord[@"date"] = [NSDate date];
            NSLog(@"Saving record %@",artworkRecord) ;
            [publicDatabase saveRecord:artworkRecord completionHandler:^(CKRecord *savedRecord, NSError *saveError){
                if (!error)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Successfully resaved artist record %@",savedRecord) ;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Insert error handling
                    NSLog(@"Failed to store record due to error %@",error) ;
                }
            }];
        }
    }
}];
```

**NSLog Prints from above code while executing **

```
 2016-03-13 23:36:50.832 ScreenShare[903:442196] Retrieved record <CKRecord: 0x134e51850; recordType=Artwork, recordID=4FEA41AA-2DE2-49C2-8B6E-513B5D3AB0AD:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__), recordChangeTag=ilr95tq6, values={
address = "Fort Bragg, CA";
date = "2016-03-14 00:39:28 +0000";
rating = 5;
title = "MacKerricher State Park";
}>


 2016-03-13 23:36:50.834 ScreenShare[903:442196] Saving record <CKRecord: 0x134e51850; recordType=Artwork, recordID=4FEA41AA-2DE2-49C2-8B6E-513B5D3AB0AD:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__), recordChangeTag=ilr95tq6, values={
address = "Fort Bragg, CA";
date = "2016-03-14 06:36:50 +0000";
rating = 5;
title = "MacKerricher State Park";
}>

2016-03-13 23:36:51.292 ScreenShare[903:442197] Successfully resaved artist record (null) 



 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title = %@", @"MacKerricher State Park"];
CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:@"Artwork" predicate:predicate];
[publicDatabase performQuery:query inZoneWithID:nil completionHandler:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        // Error handling for failed fetch from public database
         NSLog(@"Failed to retrieve record due to error %@",error) ;
    }
    else {
        // Modify the record and save it to the database
        if([results count])
        {
            CKRecord *artworkRecord = (CKRecord *)results[0] ;
            NSLog(@"Retrieved record %@",artworkRecord) ;
            //NSDate *date = ;
            artworkRecord[@"date"] = [NSDate date];
 //                Using saveRecord: method of database does not work
 //                NSLog(@"Saving record %@",artworkRecord) ;
 //                [publicDatabase saveRecord:artworkRecord completionHandler:^(CKRecord *savedRecord, NSError *saveError){
//                    if (!error)
//                    {
//                        NSLog(@"Successfully resaved artist record %@",savedRecord) ;
//                    }
//                    else
//                    {
//                        // Insert error handling
//                        NSLog(@"Failed to store record due to error %@",error) ;
//                    }
//                }];
            CKModifyRecordsOperation *saveOperation = [[CKModifyRecordsOperation alloc] initWithRecordsToSave:@[artworkRecord] recordIDsToDelete:nil] ;
            saveOperation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = ^(NSArray *savedRecords, NSArray *deletedRecordIDs, NSError * operationError)
            {
                if(operationError)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Save failed with error %@",operationError) ;
                }
            } ;
            [publicDatabase addOperation:saveOperation] ;
        }
    }
}];
```

Comment: Take a look at CKRecordSavePolicy, maybe this is not set correctly. Look into the change tags too perhaps.

Comment: Thanks, using CKModifyRecordsOperation to save instead of saveRecord works. Code is above in edit.  How do I change the tag? As far as I can tell, the CKRecordSavePolicy is only available if I use CKModifyRecordsOperation.

Comment: See, my answer below ... saveRecordsOperation.savePolicy = .ChangedKeys

Comment: Thanks, but the answer uses CKModifyRecordsOperation.  This works for me as mentioned in my edit above.  I am looking for a solution on how to make it work if I just use the saveRecord:  method on the CKDatabase instance.

Comment: Save record will only work if the record does not exist; its a limitation of the convince methods, which are intended principally as a learning route to get you on board to CloudKit. For serious/real use you need to use CKModifyRecordsOperation.

Comment: Thanks, Its weird that Apple says it should work. Pls see code snippet under Fetch and Modify Records in (or am I misinterpreting it) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/FetchingRecords/FetchingRecords.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH4-SW3

Comment: Ok, but be careful be this example is using the record ID and fetch and your using query, they would you would think be identical; but I have vague recollection that they are not.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a save with the option changed.

```
func notifyCollectionComplete(theCollection: Int) {

    let container = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.blah")
    let publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase

    let singleLink2LinkthemALL = CKRecordID(recordName: uniqReference)
    let newRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "Collections", recordID: singleLink2LinkthemALL)
    newRecord.setObject(theCollection, forKey: "theCount")

    var localChanges:[CKRecord] = []
    localChanges.append(newRecord)

    let saveRecordsOperation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: localChanges, recordIDsToDelete: nil)
    saveRecordsOperation.savePolicy = .ChangedKeys
    saveRecordsOperation.perRecordCompletionBlock =  { record, error in
        if error != nil {
            self.showAlert(message: error!.localizedDescription)
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
        // deal with conflicts
        // set completionHandler of wrapper operation if it's the case
    }
    saveRecordsOperation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { savedRecords, deletedRecordIDs, error in
        if error != nil {
            self.showAlert(message: error!.localizedDescription)
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            // deal with conflictsay
            // set completionHandler of wrapper operation if it's the case

        }
    }

    publicDB.addOperation(saveRecordsOperation)


}
```